# Share SSL certificate between VM

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, virtual-machines, azure

I have a SSL certificate for example.com, and I want to protect with it:

- My home page (example.com) running on a VM in Azure
- My servlet (servlet.example.com) which is running on a different VM (but same account) in Azure

Is there a way to do that? Or should I host the two components on the same VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a purely technical perspective, there is usually no issue with using the same certificate on multiple machines. Ensure you have the private key so you can import the certificate properly on each host.

From a functionality standpoint:
If the cert is only for `example.com` then it won't work properly for `serverlet.example.com` as the hostname won't match the record on the cert and users will get certificate warnings.

Getting a cert with a Subject Alternate Name to add additional record(s) or obtaining a wildcard cert for `*.example.com` would resolve that issue.